# How to share Wifi internet over ethernet?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ethernet, sharing

I have a Jetson nano board that doesn't have wifi and I want to share my laptop wifi with it over ethernet.

I did below things but I don't have internet on jetson:

1. On laptop I created a new wired connection and manually set the IPv4 to `192.168.2.2`, Netmask: `255.255.255.0` and Gateway: `192.168.2.2`
2. I used `sudo nm-connection-editor` and I changed the IPv4 method to "Shared to other computers"
3. On the jetson I set the wired IPv4 to manual and I gave it the IP of to `192.168.2.22` and the gateway of to `192.168.2.2`

I am able to connect the jetson from my laptop (both ping and ssh) but the jetson is not able to access the internet and when I p`ing google.com` I get this:

```bsh
jetson:~$ ping -v google.com

ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

But I also see that permission denied when I successfully ping my laptop from jetson:

```bsh
jetson:~$ ping -v 192.168.2.2

ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.04 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.54 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.48 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.60 ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What OS/release are you using?

Comment: My laptop is Ubuntu 18.04 and the jetson is using the Nvidia custom Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Configure dns entry (/etc/resolv.conf) on your Jetson nano board.